# Woocommnerce add_to_cart_url and redirect to cart afterwards

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using this code to create custom add to cart url:

```
$product = get_product(25);
echo "<a href='" . $product->add_to_cart_url() ."'>add to cart</a>";
```

My question is how can I make this redirect to cart afterwards user click this button?

I find out that the url has to look like this for this to happen:

```
href=”https://yourdomain.com/cart/?add-to-cart=25″
```

How could I make this url with add_to_cart_url call?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you want to get redirected to the cart after you added a product to it?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Are you looking for: `echo "<a href='" . wc_get_cart_url() . $product->add_to_cart_url() ."'>add to cart</a>";`

Comment: @7uc1f3r - what if there was a variable or grouped product with such url?

Comment: See: https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-custom-add-cart-urls-ultimate-guide/, part 2 & 3. It depends on how you want it to be applied